# Geospatial Index for inner structure

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

I have a collections names `locations` with data structures like:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e95263f1783ae8487be26d4"),
  "name" : "test 1", 
  "location" : { 
     "coordinate" : { 
        "latitude" : 40.731987, 
        "longitude" : -73.999701
     },
     "address": "xxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

and want to make geo queries against `location.coordinate` field.

When I'm trying to add index I get following results:

```
$> db.locations.ensureIndex( { "location.coordinate" : "2d" } )
$> **** SyntaxError: syntax error (shell):0
```

Is it possible to use geospatial index for such structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since mongodb is based on [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions) format, its better to have the longitude element first

```
"location" : { 
     "coordinate" : {        
        "longitude" : -73.999701,
        "latitude" : 40.731987 
     },
```

In the [mongodb geospatial page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-CreatingtheIndex), you can see that in multiple places

> By default, the index assumes you are indexing longitude/latitude and
>   is thus configured for a [-180..180) value range.

and

> The code assumes that you are using decimal degrees in (longitude,
>   latitude) order. This is the same order used for the GeoJSON spec.
>   Using (latitude, longitude) will result in very incorrect results, but
>   is often the ordering used elsewhere, so it is good to double-check. 
>   The names you assign to a location object (if using an object and not
>   an array) are completely ignored, only the ordering is detected.