# Error message when using geospatial indexing via Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, node.js, geospatial, mongoose

My Schema is as follows:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
ObjectId  = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId

CheckinSchema = new mongoose.Schema
  text:
    type: String, required: true
  location_latLong:
    lat:
      type: Number
    lon:
      type: Number
  location_country:
    type: String
  addedOn:
    type: Date
    default: Date.now

CheckinSchema.index
  location_latLong: '2d'

exports.CheckinSchema = CheckinSchema
```

The Model is generated separately. I get an error however when running a query. The error is:

```
count fails:{ errmsg: "exception: can't find special index: 2d for: { location_latLong: { $wi...", code: 13038, ok: 0.0 }
```

My query is:

```
{ location_latLong: { '$within': { '$box': [[ '-100', '-100' ],[ '100', '100' ]] } } }
```

So my question is.... what gives? How can I properly do Geospatial indexing in Mongoose (using Node.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis is because you have specified the wrong order in your geo index, Since mongodb is based on GeoJSON, its recommented to have the longitude field first

instead this

```
location_latLong:
    lat:
      type: Number
    lon:
      type: Number
```

use this

```
location_latLong:
    lon:
      type: Number
    lat:
      type: Number
```

The names you assign to a location object (lon,lat keys) are completely ignored, only the ordering is detected.

In [mongodb geospatial page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-CreatingtheIndex), its recommended in multiple places

> By default, the index assumes you are indexing longitude/latitude and
>   is thus configured for a [-180..180) value range

and

> The code assumes that you are using decimal degrees in (longitude,
>   latitude) order. This is the same order used for the GeoJSON spec.
>   Using (latitude, longitude) will result in very incorrect results, but
>   is often the ordering used elsewhere, so it is good to double-check.
>   The names you assign to a location object (if using an object and not
>   an array) are completely ignored, only the ordering is detected.

I have already answered this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735905/geospatial-index-for-inner-structure/7736969#7736969).

Cheer

Comment: Heads up... apparently MongoDB lies!

`"location_latLong" : { "lon" : -3.202774,
    "lzt" : 55.954155 }` is what was saved in my DB (notice the ordering) but when I use `lat`, then the `lat` is first.

Bottom line - it does do ordering of keys based on alpha sorting